# Passing in member functions as delegate parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a base class, whose ctor takes a delegate as a parameter and a class which inherits from it.

**The following works just fine:**

```
class Base
{
    public Base(Func<bool> func)
    {
    }
}

class Sub : Base
{
    public Sub()
        : base(() => true)
    {
    }

    public Sub(int i)
        : base(() => { return true; })
    {
    }
}
```

How can I pass an instance function as a parameter?
Compiler complains with error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

**What I would like to have is this:**

```
class Sub : Base
{
    public Sub()
        : base(Func)
    {
    }

    private bool Func()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It would work if `Func` was a static method. But I'd like to use instance members inside the function.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: this looks to me like an X Y problem to me, can you change your base class to just call a virtual method and just override it ?

Comment: @Boo That's an answer I would upvote... (hint hint!)

Comment: @Boo That assumes that the delegate *must* be an instance method, rather than simply allowing it to be an instance method (or anything else).

Comment: @Boo I guess that would work. I was so focused on delegates that I totally forgot about virtual or even abstract methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented this looks to me like an X Y problem to me, and seems like a flawed design, 
can you change your base class to just call a virtual method and just override it ?

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
    }

   public virtual bool func() {return false};
}   

class Sub : Base
{
  public Sub()
  {
  }

  public override bool func()
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

also you can read more about it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual

Comment: Yeah I think that's the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to also be able to put an arbitrary delegate in from the outside, you could have a property like `Func<bool> FuncProp` that either stores the given delegate or if non is given refers to the `func()` method. And then use that property wherever needed.